# jquery mobile server based login using rest api service

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

```
 Request Type : GET
 REST API Service URL : URl
 ipAddress:x.x.x.x
 port:8083
```

here EncryptedPin will be the name we entered will be encoded into base64 format...then we need to compare that encoded data in server if it is success it will give json data back
like this...

```
 Output: JSON Format
 Success Case:{"status_code":1,"status_message":"Success"}
 Failure Case: {"status_code":0,"status_message":"Failure"}
```

Comment: REST API Service URL : http://ipAddress:port/DeviceTracking/trackingServices/devices/authAdmin/{EncryptedPin}

Comment: i created one html login page...can anyone help mee...pls....                 how to write ajax call using above rest api url.....

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic json request using jQuery:

```
function myJsonRequest(){
     $.ajax({ 
         type: "GET",
         dataType: "json",
         url: "http://yourURL:yourPort/yourRestParamaters",
         success: function(data){        
            //your success handler. return data will be contained in "data" parameter.
         }
         error: function(){
             //error handler
         }
         complete: function(){
             //code you want run no matter success or failure
         }
     });
});
```

*Note: JSON requests will work on your device but when testing locally in your browser, they will fail due to cross site scripting issues. If you want a solution that will work on device and locally in browser, then use jsonp instead of json. You will also have to change your json service if you use jsonp.